# xfconf-query: create property for a plugin: Property X does not exist on channel Y

Tags: scripting, configuration, xfce

I'm trying to configure the XFCE clock plugin to use a custom format but getting

> Property "/plugins/plugin-12/digital-format" does not exist on channel "xfce4-panel".

```
$ xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /plugins -lv | grep 'clock'
/plugins/plugin-12                           clock
```

```
$ xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /plugins/plugin-12/digital-format -n '<span font="18">%T</span>%n<span font="12">%Y-%m-%d</span>'
Property "/plugins/plugin-12/digital-format" does not exist on channel "xfce4-panel".
```

Answer (score 2):

`xfconf-query` is poorly documented and picky on the parameter order. You've to specify the type (`-t` string) and `-n` or `--create` has to follow `-s` (set).

This works:

```
$ xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /plugins/plugin-12/digital-format -t "string" -s '<span font="18">%T</span>%n<span font="12">%Y-%m-%d</span>' -n
```

Credits: https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=8619

---

Consider determining the plugin number programmatically:

```
$ plugin_name="$( xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /plugins -lv | grep -E '/plugins/plugin-[0-9]+.*clock' | cut -d" " -f '1-1' )
$ xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p ${plugin_name}/digital-format -t "string" -s '<span font="18">%T</span>%n<span font="12">%Y-%m-%d</span>' -n
```

Comment: Thanks worked for me!